# why django orm follow active record pattern?

Tags: django, orm

I read their design philosophy but I can't find why they follow active record pattern.
Some people prefer data mapper pattern more.

Comment: because you have to make a decision.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrikeThank you for your answer,
But if that's the only reason, Django can choose the data mapper pattern.